# Equivalent of java arrays in c# only one index

Tags: c#

you know that in java you can use the rows of an array just by calling the index of the row, which is the equivalent in c#?

```
int[][] matrix = {{0,1},{2,3}};
```

If I want to use row 0, I only reference it like this:

```
int[] row1 = matrix[0];
```

row values will be:

```
{0,1}
```

Now how do I do this in c #? with the:

```
  int[,] matrix = {{0,1},{2,3}};
```

If I refer to the array with a single value I receive:
[image]

```
int[] row = matrix[j];
```

**I thank you**

Comment: What is keeping you from doing *exactly the same* as you do in Java?

Comment: int[][] matrix = new int[2][2]; invalid rank specifier: expected ',' or ']'

Comment: https://dotnetfiddle.net/wrsdUL

Comment: @nvoigt I do not understand your question, I uploaded my error, I wanted to do it as in java but I cannot get another error, the one above

Comment: Granted, C# is a little more verbose in array initialization: `int[][] matrix = new [] { new[]{ 0, 1 }, new[]{ 2, 3 } };`

Comment: @nvoigt I don't want to set the values directly, I just want to give it dimensions, how could I do it? Excuse me, I'm new, I thought there was only the way [,]

Comment: Did you try giving each of my inferred "new[]{}" constructs a number instead, like  "new int[2]"?

Answer (score 3):

The java and the c# are not the same. Your c# uses a multidimensional array and your java uses a jagged

Change your c# to a jagged and init it:

```
int[][] matrix = {new[]{0,1},new[]{2,3}};
```

The slight syntax different here versus java is that you have to `new[]` the inner arrays but you can omit the type because the compiler is willing to infer it from the type it sees the elements as inside the curly brackets. Omitting the `new[]` entirely gives a helpful compiler error outlining that array initializers can only be used in assignments (and this inner array is not an assignment in that sense) and suggests the use of "new" again :)

C# documentation on jagged arrays has lots of useful tips:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/arrays/jagged-arrays